# Highcharts, chart not rendering after upgrading to 5.0.10

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am experiencing some strange problem after upgrading highcharts from 5.0.6 to 5.0.10. The chart is not being displayed at all. I am defining the options with this:

```
var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'chart_container'
    },
    ...
};
```

push data to it, and then rendering it with:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

The chart is not being displayed at all. It works with all 5.0.6 or earlier versions of higcharts, but not with 5.0.10. I get no errors or warnings in the console, the 'chart_container' div is just not being displayed (I can see some svg code things in it when inspecting it).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i cannot see any problems http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/cLmfg3q7/  and  using `Highcharts JS v5.0.10 (2017-03-31)`

Comment: It seems that Highcharts 5.0.10 has a problem when being used with bootstrap classes. I had `<div id="chart_container" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">` and it did not work.

I have removed the class and the chart popped into view.

Comment: add with bootstrap see http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/cLmfg3q7/1/

Comment: @Deep3015, Thank you so much! Having the bootstrap js just before the highchart js did the trick.